# Kendo Grid Inline Editing

Tags: wcf-rest, kendo-ui

I am attempting to build a Restful service that will allow me to do inline editing with the Kendo UI Grid.

I am unfamiliar with both Kendo UI and Restful services, so I don't know where to begin.

I am using http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html as a reference, but it doesn't show I can I do inline editing with a Restful service.

Does anybody know how I could make this work or where I could go to view examples?

, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what the controller looks like for inline editing https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net-mvc/blob/master/grid-crud/Controllers/HomeController.cs

if you have northwind on your sqlexpress you can run this example.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the parameter map configuration value which you can use to map for working with RESTful type URL's.

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/index.html

Go to Configuration / Transport / parameterMap

You will want to use the parameterMap function to adust your create update and destroy URL's with the proper ID.